# Convergent sequence question....

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have a homework question that I am not sure how to begin. We are asked to suppose $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are sequences such that $\{a_n^2 + b_n^2\} \rightarrow 0$.

We have to prove $\{a_n\} \rightarrow 0$  and $\{b_n\} \rightarrow 0$.  I thought that I could say that $a_n \leq a_n^2  \leq a_n^2 +b_n^2 \rightarrow 0$, thus $\{a_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n^2 +b_n^2\}$ then it must also converge to $0$?

Comment: Your inequality $a_n\leq a_n^2$ is not true when $0<a_n<1$. But $0\leq a_n^2\leq a_n^2+b_n^2$ does imply $\lim a_n^2=0$. And indeed it follows that $\lim a_n=0$. Try an $\epsilon$ proof, it is a good exercise.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the inequality does not hold when 0<an<1.  I obviously never considered it.  I'm working on an epsilon proof now.

Answer (score 2):

If we denote by $u_n=(a_n,b_n)$ the sequence of $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the Euclidean norm $||.||$ then we have
$$||u_n||^2=a_n^2+b_n^2\to0\iff u_n=(a_n,b_n)\to(0,0)\iff a_n\to0\, \mathrm{and}\, b_n\to0$$

Answer (score 1):

In general we can't say $a_n \leq a_n^2$.  On the other hand if $a_n^2 + b^2 \rightarrow 0$, then $0 \leq a_n^2 \leq a_n^2 + b_n^2$ implies that $a_n^2 \rightarrow 0$.  From this, we can use the continuity of square root to show that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ (You may need to prove this if you haven't already done so).